# How to create grok filter logic for Nginx error log

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to write Logstash filter using grok logic pattern. I am logging nginx error log. My problem is the log from the nginx contains 2 field which are not present in every error logs. I have used this logic pattern to to filter the log. I can write 2 patterns and add those 2 pattern inside the logstash filter config file. But is there any way to do it in a single logic pattern?

Logic pattern:

```
(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}[./]%{MONTHNUM}[./]%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}) \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] %{POSINT:pid}#%{NUMBER:threadid}\: \*%{NUMBER:connectionid} %{GREEDYDATA:message}, client: %{IP:client}, server: %{GREEDYDATA:server}, request: "%{GREEDYDATA:request}", upstream: "%{URI:upstream}", host: "%{IPORHOST:host}", referrer: "(?:%{URI:referrer})"
```

Sample Log 1:

> 2021/09/16 15:58:59 [warn] 104255#104555: *611541 an upstream response
> is buffered to a temporary file
> /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/6/06/0000000066 while reading upstream,
> client: 100.16.127.2, server: webservice.example.com, request:
> "GET /example/contents/common/img/somename.png
> HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "https://120.27.2.87:43/example/contents/common/img/somename.png", host: "webservice.example.com", referrer:
> "https://webservice.example.com/example/view/common/api_use/"

Sample Log 2:

> 2021/09/16 10:38:54 [error] 104555#104555: *611070 open()
> "/usr/share/nginx/html/webservice.example.com/xxxxxxxx" failed
> (2: No such file or directory), client: 120.36.230.2, server:
> webservice.example.com, request: "GET /xxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1", host:
> "webservice.example.com

As you can see, sample log 2 does not have upstream and referrer field. My logic pattern works for the logs containing upstream and referrer field. Please suggest me what should I do? Should I use 2 logic pattern inside Logstash filter config or do I need to modify my current logic pattern to match both type of logs.

Comment: Be carrefull it looks missing " at the end of sample log 2

Answer (score 0):

If you issue is only that some fields are missing, then I would suggest you to not match the fields directly, but to use `kv` logstash filter. It let's you define options for key-value type of structures inside of string, then it splits it and makes a map inside of event.

You would need to capture whole key-value part of your log into one field containing all the fields and values and then set the options such as `field_split_pattern` to match your case and then set `target` to field you want the map in after `kv` is done parsing.

More information [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html).

In you case it would be something like this

```
kv {
  field_split_pattern => ", "
  value_split_pattern => ": "
  target => "field_name"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this 2 sample in the grok expression, just saif upstream and referrer are optionnal like this :

```
[, referrer\: "(?:%{URI:referrer})"]?
```

So finally the full line which i've tested on [grokdebug](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) tools and it works for your 2 logs sample :

```
%{YEAR}[./]%{MONTHNUM}[./]%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] %{POSINT:pid}#%{NUMBER:threadid}\: \*%{NUMBER:connectionid} %{GREEDYDATA:message}, client\: %{IP:client}, server\: %{GREEDYDATA:server}, request\: "%{GREEDYDATA:request}", [upstream\: "%{URI:upstream}", ]?host\: "%{IPORHOST:host}"[, referrer\: "(?:%{URI:referrer})"]?
```